# Hidden and show a div with google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I trying to animate an hidden div with google map (a personalized map). 
I've seen the other questions but this is a different js, I think.

The js has a function "setup Gmaps()" and I suppose is an "initialize" problem.
Right now I have a toggle jQuery function but not work .

```
    $("#showmapa").toggle(
    function(){
    $(".google-maps").animate({top: "0"},400, "easeOutQuad", function() {
    setupGmaps();
    });
    },
    function(){
    $(".google-maps").animate({top: "-265"}, 400, "easeOutQuad");
    }
    );
```

I also tried with *opacity* but the same problem

```
        $("#showmapa").toggle(
    function(){
    $("#mapa").animate({opacity: '1'}, 300, "easeOutQuad", function() {
    setupGmaps();
    });
    },
    function(){
    $("#mapa").animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, "easeOutQuad");
    }
    );
```

This is my hosted js file in dropbox http://bit.ly/zSLGgx , I don't understand why with setupGmaps() initialize not work...

Thank you so much in advance.

Marko

Comment: Do you have a link to the complete web page where you're trying to render the map?

Comment: Thank you andresf for your reply. 
This is the link http://bit.ly/xswChr . You have to click on "MOSTRA EL MAPA >" and you will see that the map not work. 
After a 2/3 times refresh the map work good,  but when you click on another button menú and come back the map not work again.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue.  What exactly do you mean by the map not working. I'm able to see it appear and disappear, and I can pan and zoom with it.  I'm using Chrome on a Mac.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on a PC. Try to click the link bit.ly/xswChr  than click other menú button and come back to the page. The map not work good. If you want I can upload a screenshot.

Right now this happens only with Chrome and Opera

Comment: I see it now.  This is likely a jquery issue rather than a Google Maps issue.  I did notice that you call $(document).ready(function() twice in test.html (line 30 and line 49).  Why are you doing that?  You should move all of your code under 1 instance of the $(document).ready(function() call.  I also suggest not using animation on the #mapa element to see if that clears the issue.  If it does, then you know it's a jquery issue rather than a Maps API issue.

Comment: Thank you andresf! You are right about the js document ready call function. I tried also without the fade out div's map and work good. I think is a jQuery problem .... I don't know, could be an incompatibility between jQuery and Google Api.

Comment: Moving my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I see it now. This is likely a jquery issue rather than a Google Maps issue. I did notice that `you call $(document).ready(function()` twice in test.html (line 30 and line 49). Why are you doing that? You should move all of your code under 1 instance of the `$(document).ready(function()` call. I also suggest not using animation on the `#mapa` element to see if that clears the issue. If it does, then you know it's a jquery issue rather than a Maps API issue.